# How Can I Get The Build Script To Find My File?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Working through the visual studio C/C++ tutorial here, so I can start learning C: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

getting this error:

> c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'helloworld.cpp': No
>   such file or directory

file structure looks like this:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Aaf.png)

I've tried moving the helloworld.cpp file up into the .vscode directory, and back down out (it's out in the tutorial).  This doesn't make a difference.

Tried putting a direct file path like so into the tasks.json file, like this:

```
"args": [
                "/EHsc",
                "/Zi",
                "/Fe:",
                "helloworld.exe",
                "${C:WindowsSystem32projectshelloworld.vscodehelloworld.cpp}"
            ],
```

but then I get the following error:

> cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename

Can someone help?  Thx.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use Visual Studio Code for this instead of an actual IDE like Visual Studio. The two are not the same.

Comment: There are more ways to learn C than with VS Code. Anyway, did you follow the tutorial *absolutely exactly*? Especially with such a heavy IDE you can make a lot of little errors. You might like to try a lighter IDE, but for good reasons SO is not the place for recommendations.

Comment: So The problem is basically just that this ide doesn't really work with C?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I had to open the developer console as an administrator on my machine in order to mkdir, which differs from the tutorial. This took me to my root windows directory instead of the VS directory that would normally be opened with the developer console. Now that everything is in the right place, it works. I guess there are files in the background the compiler needs which live in the vs code directory, and if you put a file elsewhere code gets confused.